# How to Blend Animations - Always Fails for Me

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

Extra Information: https://youtu.be/fhvEo-Ct_FU See description for transcript of information.

I have a series of idle poses as animation files. Each of these are static, or just arm or head motoin. Thay are supposed to be used alongside an "Idle Noise" animation. However, none of the blend modes seem to support this.

[image]

You can see here the subtle motion the noise track gives. The mess of bones isn't supposed be an issue, since the change in motion from this start position is all I need, but I can't get any blend mode to take just this motion and apply it over the 'realistic, full-body' pose it's to work with.

I need a way of taking the first frame of the new animation as the 'zero' and have any additional animation from that zero to be added to the underlying pose. Isn't the 'Add' mode supposed to do something like that?

This is the pose without the Noise track enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all the poses are on the same armature OR if all the poses are on identical armatures (meaning armatures with the same number of bones and with the same bone names), you can create a pose library with all the poses you want saved to it. Then you can attach this pose library to a project file containing the armature that you actually wish to animate, and all the saved poses will become available to it. The Pose Library is created and accessed from the *Object Data* tab of the *Properties Panel* (while an *armature* is selected), then under the **Pose Library** section).

To blend the poses during animation: Make sure you're in Pose Mode any time you are doing anything with the Pose Library. After choosing poses in the Pose library one by one (the poses become listed in the library when they are saved to it), you must click the "+" icon to save the pose to the library. Only selected bones are affected by any changes in pose that are brought about by using the pose library, so keep this in mind. You can keyframe any pose activated in the Pose Library (using the "magnifying glass" icon to apply the pose to the currently selected armature) using your standard workspace windows and editors as you normally would. Then you can choose another pose from the library at another frame, and keyframe again to get interpolation between the two poses.

If it turns out that the desired poses were originally from different armatures, this can all still be done, but extra steps are required. You would need to open the extra versions of the armatures, and for each one, select all its bones in Pose Mode, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to copy all the pose positions of all selected bones, then select a different armature -- the one you eventually want to animate -- in Object Mode, switch to Pose Mode, select all its bones, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste those pose positions to this other armature, save the new pose to your pose library, and then continue with these steps until you have added all the needed poses to the pose library. Your pose library can be saved and appended to other files also, which can be handy. This way, you don't need all of your armatures in one file to get the pose library built. That said, it might actually be easier to append the armatures to the file containing the pose library instead of the other way around, as this might entail less chance of pose library corruption. So, you could append each armature to the file containing the pose library, add the pose of that armature to the pose library, save everything, and append a new armature to the file containing the pose library, then save the new pose to that library. This might be the preferred approach if none of your desired poses are on armatures that all exist within one single file. If they do, then simply add their poses to the pose library all in the same session, one at a time, and then get rid of the armatures you no longer need afterwards. You should end up with one armature and many available poses. Don't delete any of the other armatures until you know all your poses work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @R-800, but it's not really relevant to the question. I'm trying to find if I can blend a static pose with a second action without breaking the pose. I'll add some more info to the question.

Comment: Actions and poses are two different things. One can't ever be blended with the other, as this makes no sense. Poses are discrete collections of joint orientations in space. Actions are discrete collections of related keyframes.

Comment: I've added a video which should clear things up.

Comment: Do you see what I'm trying to accomplish, @R-800,or you still say it isn't possible?